# TCL script to open multiple xterms and fire jobs in the opened xterms

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, xterm

I want to write a script in tcl to perform the below operation.

```
set ss test1

if ([string compare $ss "test1"]) {
   ## Open new xterm
   Ex:- bsub -Ip -n 1 -M 100 -q <queue_name> xterm &
   ## go to dir2 
   Ex:- cd dir2 
   ## then source test1_file in the opened xterm
} 
if ([string compare $ss "test2"]) {
   ## Open new xterm
   Ex:- bsub -Ip -n 1 -M 100 -q <queue_name> xterm &
   ## go to dir2 
   Ex:- cd dir2
   ## then source test2_file
}
```

when I try with xterm -e "cd dir1" & in the unix terminal xterm was opened and it got killed automatically.

Please help me how to do this.

Thanks and Regards,
Gunnesh.

Comment: Note: `string compare` returns 0 when the strings are equal, meaning that the body of the `if` command will only be executed when the strings differ! I suspect you want the `eq` operator, or at least `string equal`. If neither of those are available, your Tcl is horribly outdated. Also, the condition argument of the `if` command normally goes between {}, not ().

Comment: The xterm isn't getting killed, it's exiting because the given command is run and immediately exits (With an error if it doesn't use a shell to run it).

Comment: Thank You Shawn, How can I monitor the xterm ? Means is there any ID ? that I can use in my script to know the xterm is ongoing or completed or exited due to error?

Comment: Are you trying to control xterm itself (it isn't designed for it) or some processes running inside it? Running, say, expect from inside bsub would make for a more effective approach, though without the GUI. Expect is designed to do *automation* of the sorts of things you run inside xterm...

Comment: Thank you Donal . My requirement is like i want to check the status of my source file (test1_file). I taught It can happen with monitoring xterm. With your explanation I came to know that Its not possible. I will check for any other method to suit my requirement. Thanks once again to All.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely, that this would help, but I use something like:

1) create *run.sh* containing:

```
#! /bin/bash
eval "$@"
echo "Press return to continue"
read
```

In Windows, it would be *run.bat*:

```
@echo off
%*
pause
```

2) to execute a command (say, "dir"), use Tcl command:

```
exec xterm -e ./run.sh dir
```

This would display a console, a result of executed command and a prompt "Press...".